# Implementing a method taking a block to use as callback

Tags: objective-c, ios, callback, objective-c-blocks

I would like to write a method similar to this:

```
+(void)myMethodWithView:(UIView *)exampleView completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

I've basically stripped down the syntax taken from one of Apple's class methods for `UIView`:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

And would expect it to be used like so:

```
[myFoo myMethodWithView:self.view completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"call back success");
                 }];
```

My question is how can I implement this?  If someone can point me to the correct documentation that would be great, and a very basic example would be much appreciated (or a similar answer on Stack Overflow -- I couldn't find one). I still don't quite know enough about delegates to determine whether that is even the correct approach!

I've put a rough example of what I would have expected it to be in the implementation file, but as I can't find info it's guess work.

```
+ (void)myMethod:(UIView *)exampleView completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {
    // do stuff

    if (completion) {
        // what sort of syntax goes here? If I've constructed this correctly!
    }

}
```

Comment: I wonder why no one has mentioned the fact that the `finished` in the parameter type is quite unnecessary in this example...

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can call a block like a regular function:

```
BOOL finished = ...;
if (completion) {
    completion(finished);
}
```

So that means implementing a complete block function using your example would look like this:

```
+ (void)myMethod:(UIView *)exampleView completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {
    if (completion) {
        completion(finished);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was painfully straight forward, many thanks! Site says it's too early to accept the answer, I will do once I'm back on the computer

Comment: Also take a note that in your example you create block on stack, so there is possibility that block will die before it is executed. To avoid this, make [[completion copy] autorelease] in your method, that accepts block.

Comment: @TimurKuchkarov - can you past some code so I can see where the [completion copy] should go in the method?  All a little confusing to my simple mind :)

Comment: "Typically, you shouldn’t need to copy (or retain) a block. You only need to make a copy when you expect the block to be used after destruction of the scope within which it was declared. Copying moves a block to the heap.". Also a good link is - http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-15-stack-and-heap-objects-in-objective-c.html . As for me, I'm generally copying at the start of method where block is passed.

Comment: when i copypaste + (void)myMethod:(UIView *)exampleView completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {
    if (completion) {
        completion(finished);
    }
}

Comment: sorry but ı can't understand this answer? what is completion ? it's typdef ? can you add a tutorial ? thnak you

Comment: @ErhanDemirci the `completion` is the actual block. It is defined in the method signature. (void (^)(BOOL finished))completion allows invoking a completion() method that is used as a call back. Check out apples docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: Thank you @jonhathon . how method can method understand mission is finished ?

Answer (score 5):

I would highly recommend that you read up on [Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1) to understand what is happening.

Comment: when I copypaste + (void)myMethod:(UIView *)exampleView completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {
    if (completion) {
        completion(finished);
    }
} I get "use of undeclared identifier finished"....

Answer (score 1):

If you're specially looking for a doc, to create custom method using blocks, then the following link is the one which explains almost everything about it. :)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html

I happen to answer quite a same question recently, have a look at this: [Declare a block method parameter without using a typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486976/objective-c-declare-a-block-method-parameter-without-using-a-typedef/7397430#7397430)