# Creating a custom method with completion block

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, nsoperation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing a method taking a block to use as callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180552/implementing-a-method-taking-a-block-to-use-as-callback)

I couldn't find any clear explanation about how to implement a method that executes a completion block.

I know that NSOperation can be subclasses and used with calling `setCompletionBlock:` . Anyone knows if this is possible just by implementing in the m. file?

Comment: Thank you, I searched stackoverflow for "completion block". No wonder why this never showed up!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may not believe it, but there is a [Code Samurai Article](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/02/practical-design-patterns-with-blocks.html?m=1) which covers the exact ground of your question!  About a third of the way down, they subclass NSOperation with an example completion block.

Comment: I saw that article but if you read my question, I was asking about a pure implementation way of doing it. But still thank you!