# teardown for whole test suite

Tags: ios, iphone, unit-testing

I have a test suite in which there are many test classes each one having many tests.
Now if I define

```
+ (void)tearDown
```

in any class, then it will be run after all the tests of that class only.
and

```
- (void)tearDown
```

will be run after each test.
I want to define a tearDown method and want it to be run after all the tests of all the classes.
Fox eg, if I have 5 classes each having 7 tests each. So I want to run this tearDown function after all the 35 tests.

Comment: - Which test framework are you using?
- Why do you need to do a final teardown?

Comment: I am using sentest. And in xcode 5, my test coverage generation failed. I searched and found that we have to run __gcov_flush to get .gcda files built. To do that, I have to run this function after whole test suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking for a way to call __gcov_flush() after all tests have finished, see https://qualitycoding.org/ios-7-code-coverage/. The latest code from Google Toolbox for Mac shows how to do this using test observers, with versions for both SenTestingKit and XCTest.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you can take note of completion of each method using a global variable/flag using `completion block methods` like this:

```
+ (void)myMethod:(UIView *)exampleView completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {
    if (completion) {
        completion(finished);
    }
}
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7180552/1146089) for a better explanation.

Then create a method that checks if all taskes are executed and that runs final test when needed like this:

```
- (void)finalTest {
    if (CHECK GLOBAL FLAG FOR COMPLETION OF OTHER TASKES) {
        // do final test
    } else {
        // repeat check after 0.1 seconds
        [self performSelector:@selector(finalTest)
               withObject:nil
               afterDelay:0.1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah!!
I can do like this but for that I will have to change my existing tests which I don't want. Can't I add some special function like teardown for whole suite?