# Custom completion block for my own method

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have just discovered completion blocks:

```
 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                     }];
```

What do I need to do to have my own method take a completion block?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62671217/1023074

Answer (score 234, accepted):

**1) Define your own completion block,**

```
typedef void(^myCompletion)(BOOL);
```

**2) Create a method which takes your completion block as a parameter,**

```
-(void) myMethod:(myCompletion) compblock{
    //do stuff
    compblock(YES);
}
```

**3)This is how you use it,**

```
[self myMethod:^(BOOL finished) {
    if(finished){
        NSLog(@"success");
    }
}];
```

[image]

Comment: compclock(YES) is the same as return compclock = YES ?

Comment: Yes, You got it, we can put compclock(YES)/compclock(NO) depending on the requirement, we can return NO for failure completions here

Comment: track the returned value: if(finished) NSLog(@"success");else NSLog(@"failure");

Comment: If you're a C/C++ programmer, then I find it very easy to remember the syntax of block declaration using a pointer to function syntax. The only thing you need to do is replace "*" in C/C++ function-pointer with "^" ...thought it might help someone in future :)

Comment: For more than one parameter in the block, use a comma to separate. E.g. `completion:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSString* videoPath))`

Comment: What if my method is prepareForSegue ?!?! any possible way to use it for that? Like if user wants to go to the next page and I need to show waiting animation once the prepareForSegue starts preparing and do compBlock(YES) inside prepareForSegue method?

Answer (score 25):

You define the block as a custom type:

```
typedef void (^ButtonCompletionBlock)(int buttonIndex);
```

Then use it as an argument to a method:

```
+ (SomeButtonView*)buttonViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title 
                          cancelAction:(ButtonCompletionBlock)cancelBlock
                      completionAction:(ButtonCompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

When calling this in code it is just like any other block:

```
[SomeButtonView buttonViewWithTitle:@"Title"
                       cancelAction:^(int buttonIndex) {
                             NSLog(@"User cancelled");
                   } 
                     completionAction:^(int buttonIndex) {
                             NSLog(@"User tapped index %i", buttonIndex);
                   }];
```

If it comes time to trigger the block, simply call `completionBlock()` (where `completionBlock` is the name of your local copy of the block).

Answer (score 2):

Block variables are similar in syntax to function pointers in C.

Because the syntax is ugly they are often typedefed, however they can also be declared normally.

```
typedef void (^MyFunc)(BOOL finished);

- (void)myMethod:(MyFunc)func
{
}
```

See this answer for non typedef:

[Declare a block method parameter without using a typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486976/declare-a-block-method-parameter-without-using-a-typedef)

Comment: ok thanks i'll check it out, it is a little bit complicated to me where do i have the typedef ?

Comment: You can put the typedef in the header file, before the `@interface`.