# How to write a completion block in objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm having trouble creating completion blocks. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436831/how-to-write-an-objective-c-completion-block)
. It works for me, but I don't quite understand this. Now I'm still confused and don't know how to write a block myself. Are there any batter ways to understand blocks? Also, when should I use it? Is there anything that can replace blocks?

Should I create it as a property? Method perimeter? Do they have difference in efficiency?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you need to know? How to write a method that takes a block? How to pass a block to a method?

Comment: this kind of question is too broad, you aren't asking a specific question even about syntax, or presenting a problem

Comment: That's what makes me confused. I don't know how to create a block.  Beginner in blocks :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out http://fuckingblocksyntax.com for syntax. 
For personal choice I like to return value and error in the completion block (similar to iOS framework pattern) 
As an example;

declaration

```
- (void)fetchStuff:(void (^)(id value,NSError *error))completion;
```

calling the function

```
// async fetch
[object fetchStuff:^(id value, NSError *error) {
    // do stuff with value
}];
```

Comment: What's the difference between a block as a perimeter and block as property?  Do they have difference in efficiency?

Comment: I think it is safe to say they are both same. But I am not really sure.