# defining a completion block parameter list error

Tags: ios, objective-c

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324095/custom-completion-block-for-my-own-method) SO answer shows how to define a completion block like this

```
@interface ViewController ()
typedef void(^myCompletion)(BOOl);
@end

@implementation ViewController
```

However when I try to do that in my ViewController, I get this error

```
a parameter list without type is only allowed in a function definition
```

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Is "BOOl" a typo error?

Comment: @larme ugh that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BOOl` doesn't exist. `bool` and `BOOL` do.
You get error, because `BOOl` is not a type.