# How to write and pass a completion block parameter for a method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, completion-block

I have a method that basically uses this:

```
-(void)myMethodwithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)time{
[UIView animateWithDuration:time
                     animations:^{
                          // do thing here
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                          //do completion stuff here
                     }
     ];
```

What I don't know how to do is to write/package up a parameter so that I can write the code I want to execute, and then simply pass it into the method like I do with `time`.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is all covered in Apple's [Blocks Programming Topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502) document.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324095/custom-completion-block-for-my-own-method

Answer (score 1):

To accept a block with `void` return value, and a `BOOL` param:

```
- (void)myMethodWithBlock:(void (^)(BOOL someCoolBool))block {
    if (block) {
        block(YES);
    }
}
```

To call it:

```
[self myMethodWithBlock:^(BOOL someCoolBool) {
    if (hasParams) {
        //....
    }
}];
```

Quick reference: [FBS.com](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com)