# Mixing Blocks and Delegates in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Is it possible to run a block when a delegate receives a message?

For example, if I had a framework that took a void block as a parameter (we'll call it the "success" block), and was using an NSURLConnection delegate to do stuff with those method arguments, when I receive a response from the webpage, how can I call the "success" block passed in the method parameters?

This is **really** hard for me to explain, and I obviously don't have any code for this, but I can clarify if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for: [Custom completion block for my own method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16324095)

Comment: Exactly that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You absolutely can. That is how *all* completion handlers / callbacks work. In fact, that is what a block is *for*.

To take a simple example, consider this NSURLConnection class method:

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                          queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
              completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response,
                                          NSData *data,
                                          NSError *connectionError))handler
```

For the third parameter, you pass a block. And when the request is all over, some time in the future, what does NSURLConnection do? It *calls* the block.

So, you can do exactly the same that NSURLConnection is doing. You can write a method that takes a block, you hold on to the block, you do something that perhaps takes some time, and then later you *call* the block.

Comment: How do you store / call the block?

Comment: You store it the same way you store anything - in a variable / property. And you call it the same way you call any function: you say its name followed by parentheses (you know, with arguments in them).

Comment: I'll try it out when I get home, I had no idea this was possible! Marking as correct answer assuming you're right, thanks!

Comment: You might want to read Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: "I had no idea this was possible" But then one has to wonder what you thought a block _was_ all this time. Every block you've ever used works this way. A block is to call. Otherwise what's the point of it? :) The only difference is that you were always letting someone _else_ receive it, hang on to it, and call it. Now, _you_ will receive it, hang on to it, and call it.

Comment: @Vig I've worked with blocks before and can honestly say, this website is a life savor. Love it.

Comment: @matt To answer your rhetorical question: Magic.

Comment: "To answer your rhetorical question: Magic" Oh. Well if you already knew the answer, why are you asking in the first place? :))))))

Comment: Here is an example from my own code, where I do something _very_ similar to what you are describing: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyDownloader.m

Comment: That was extremely helpful @matt, thanks. Now I have a model requesting data from a website with a completion handler, BUT if I were to for example send a message to that method twice in a row without waiting for the first one to finish, the second message overrides the first message and it screws stuff up. Is there anyway around this? EDIT: I could put the second call in the completion handler for the first call, but is there any easier way?

Comment: @ZaneHelton But that's a completely separate question. And a very interesting one! I wish you'd ask it as a real question, and please blip me in a comment here and point me to it. Thanks!!! But please note - my example that I pointed you to works perfectly if MyDownloader receives a new "start downloading" request while it is already downloading something, because it associates each completion handler with that individual download. So nothing gets overridden.