# In Objective-C when implementing a method that calls a completion handler after a background task is finished how to determine thread safety?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have recently modified an existing project and modified some methods from returning a value (BOOL) to call a completion block.
I followed this very good answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16324193/942165

Now I have my method that calls the completion block, it is working great, but I am afraid it can unpredictably fail for
not being thread safe.

I have my declaration of the block:

```
typedef void(^myCompletion)(id, BOOL);
```

Following is my method with completion handler:

```
-(void)myMethodThatTakesAnArgument:(id)object completionHandler:(myCompletion)completionblock {
    //do things that are allowed in the main thread:
    //...
    //...
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue =
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

        [self doWorkButReturnImmediately];
        BOOL workIsNotFinished = [self isJobFinished];

        NSDate *processingStart = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval timeElapsed = 0.0;
        while (workIsNotFinished && timeElapsed < 15.0) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
            timeElapsed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:processingStart];
            workIsNotFinished = [self isJobFinished];
        }

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          // Return Result
          completionblock(object,YES);
      });
  });   
}
```

Following is my caller method:

```
- (void)callerMethod {

    NSArray *arrayOfObjects = [self prepareArrayOfObjects];

    NSMutableArray *unprocessedObjects = [arrayOfObjects mutableCopy];

    for (NSString *string in arrayOfObjects) {

        [self myMethod:string completionblock:^(id obj, BOOL success) {
        
        [unprocessedObjects removeObject:string];
        if(success){
            // do something with obj
            NSLog(@"success");
        }
        
        if ([unprocessedObjects count] == 0) {
        
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            
                // Everything is done, act accordingly.
            
            });
        
            }
        
        }
  }
}
```

I suspect this scenario can somehow fail and I am thinking of adding some thread safety code. I am not a lot expert of the subject, but it appears to me that probably, @synchronized could be the way to go. So I would like to embed the code of the called method in some @synchronized statements, but I am not sure if this is necessary in this case, and, if it is, I am not sure on where to specifically put the statements, I think probably in the part that is dispatched in a background queue. In the code, I have included a simple object that is passed back in the completion handler that could act as the object to pass to @synchronized. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thread-safe issue that jumps out at me is `isJobFinished`. You're calling it repeatedly from a second thread, so its implementation would have to be thread safe.

However, this is *NOT* the way to check for completion. Just remember this rule: Polling bad. Semaphores good.

This is a much cleaner, and more efficient, implementation and avoids any issue with `isJobFinished`:

```
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t jobFinishedSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        [self doWorkSignalingWhenDone:jobFinishedSemaphore];
        
        if ( dispatch_semaphore_wait(jobFinishedSemaphore, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 15*NSEC_PER_SEC)) ) {
            // work timed out
        } else {
            // work successfully completed
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Return Result
                completionblock(self,YES);
            });
        }
    });
}

- (void)doWorkSignalingWhenDone:(dispatch_semaphore_t)finishedSemaphore
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
        // do some work in the background
        // ...
        // signal work is finished
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(finishedSemaphore);
    });
}
```

If modifying `doWorkButReturnImmediately` isn't practical, but `isJobFinished` is observable, you can do something similar using a value observer. In the observer method, signal the semaphore when the value of `isJobFinished` changes from `NO` to `YES`.

The best solution for passing `jobFinishedSemaphore` to the observer method would be to make it an instance variable of the object. However, that means you could only be running one of these tasks at a time. If must have multiple jobs in flight at once, or you just *cannot* edit the vars in the class, this should work:

```
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t jobFinishedSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

    [self addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"isJobFinished"
              options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
              context:(__bridge void * _Nullable)(jobFinishedSemaphore)];   /* WARNING! not retained */

    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        [self doWorkButReturnImmediately];
        
        if ( dispatch_semaphore_wait(jobFinishedSemaphore, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 15*NSEC_PER_SEC)) ) {
            // work timed out
        } else {
            // work successfully completed
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Return Result
                completionblock(object,YES);
            });
        }
        
        // Note: this is "mostly" thread safe because this block still retains a reference to
        //  jobFinishedSemaphore, so that semephore has not been destroyed yet.
        // Remove the value observer before the reference to jobFinishedSemaphore goes out of scope.
        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isJobFinished" context:(__bridge void * _Nullable)(jobFinishedSemaphore)];
        // at this point jobFinishedSemaphore goes out of scope, but the observer has been removed so it
        //  should no longer get sent with the (now invalid void*) reference to jobFinishedSemaphore.
    });
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary*)change
                       context:(void*)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"isJobFinished"])
        {
        if (   ![change[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] boolValue]  // value was NO
            && [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue] ) // value now YES
            {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal((__bridge dispatch_semaphore_t _Nonnull)(context));
            }
        }
}
```

The scary part of this code is that you're passing a non-retained copy of the semaphore pointer to the observer. But as long as you remove the observer before the semaphore is destroyed, you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks James ! I am trying to achieve the KVO mechanism. If you can, could you please share an example snippet of this last technique you suggested ? How do I obtain a reference to the semaphore in order to signal it, is it in observeValueForKeypath: ?

Comment: Wow, you're really going to make me work for this aren't you? I've updated the answer to include an observer based solution.

Comment: Be aware that there is, technically, an *extremely* unlikely race condition in the second version. The only reasonable way to fix that is to store all of the semaphore objects in the object (using a set or keyed collection) and create and destroy them all on the main thread. If you can't modify the code for the class this could be accomplished using `objc_setAssociatedObject()`.

Comment: Really Thanks James, I made you work indeed ! Invaluable help for me ! Thanks again !